# keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\AndroidWorkspace\androidKey\public.jks (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, apk

I am to trying to create a signed app in Android Studio, but i am stuck at this error which says

> keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\AndroidWorkspace\androidKey\public.jks (The system cannot find the path specified)

I get this error when i am creating a new key store. i am confused, why would it search for this key, when i am trying to create a new one.

> Android Studio : V1.1.0
>
> JRE: 1.8.0_25-b18 amd64

Comment: Did you set your build.gradle to sign the apk?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti, that did the trick, i had missed that part, thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Manual modifying the build.gradle(Module:app) file to sign the apk did the work. This is the code I've included in build.gradle.

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("release.keystore")
        storePassword "******"
        keyAlias "******"
        keyPassword "******"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

On windows if you are trying to generate the key using the `cmd` and copying the command from the android docs which is the following:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\USER_NAME\key.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key
```

you need to change the `USER_NAME` part to what ever is your PC name which is a folder name in the users folder and then execute the code. For example if my users folder name is Taba then I have to execute this code:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\Taba\key.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key
```

Or you can even change the directory to where ever you like the `.jks` file to be saved.

Comment: I'm an experienced developer with the same problem and now I go "DUH," that's obvious.

Answer (score 17):

Windows path might be the problem

```
 keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key
```

Use a path like above
where the slash used is backward slanting.

Answer (score 2):

If the error says "permission denied" above, then if you run the command in cmd, run cmd as administrator.

Answer (score 2):

**Before:**

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
```

**Now:**

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore C:\upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 1000
```

Now, it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the build directory at the app module level and then File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... . I guess it caches some configs there.

Answer (score 1):

When generating the .aab file for Android, java SDK normally finds it hard to locate a safe default storage location, hence the `Access Denied` Error.
So what I did is changed the default keytool path to the homepage of Disk D i.e `D:\>` then launched `cmd` in that Directory, Then pasted the command into sth like this:

```
D:\>  keytool -genkey -v -keystore d:\appname.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias appname
```

Then it worked, then copy the generated file to your `android/app/src`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to update the Java JDK, and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly saying that it can't find the path to save the generated keystore. Change the path to a known location, it will work.

You can follow the steps from this [article](https://medium.com/@kondaveetibalasubramanyam/how-to-generate-keystore-on-a-windows-cdb036bb92b2)

Answer (score 0):

run cmd as adminstrator then:
keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key.jks

Answer (score 0):

if you are using window you should run android studio as administrator and it will be ok

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I faced the same error on the server using the CMD window with Admin access. No problem with my laptop. My colleague can run the keytool command on the same server without any problem. I was unable to find out why it was not working from my end. I decided to use PowerShell and it worked.